# Material-ui 4.11.4 - Grid: items in column require container direction='row' to display correctly (??)

Tags: html, css, material-ui, css-grid

I want to have several div's in column, centered on the page axis and stretched in width as much as the div width allows it. I am using the `<Grid>` component (both `container` and `item`) of material-ui 4.11.4 (latest version):

[image: centered column of Grid items]

In the previous image all Grid items have `xs={12}`, while "page body" has `xs={10}`.

I would expect that the following container would do the job:

```
<Grid container direction='column' justify='center' alignItems='stretch'>
    ....
</Grid>
```

However, if I want the effect shown in the previous image, I have to give the `container` a property `direction='row'`.

If I give `direction='column'`, all grid items are aligned on the left side of the screen:

[image: grid items stashed on the left side]

This seems wrong to me. I have also checked on the FlexyBoxes site, and it requires `'flex-direction:column'`:

[image: FlexyBoxes requires direction=column]

What am I missing here? Why do I get a column ordering only if I specify `direction='row'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened [this issue on github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26594), which so far has gotten no comments.

I am systematically using `direction='row'` in this kind of column `Grid`'s, which is weird but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this a few months ago. Just add a `<Grid item xs={1}/>` above and below the Page Body grid item. Still you may find other solutions but this one should work fine.